# Is it possible to model bind an entire object in an Angular controller method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have the following Interface defined in TypeScript:

```
interface Person {
    Id: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Age: number;
}
```

I have a `.html` partial that contains an Angular `ng-submit="submit()"` directive on an HTML `form` element. Here is an example element from inside the `form`:

```
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="FirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
```

What I'd like to have is the following call on sumbit map form values to the object argument on the `submit` call like below:

```
$scope.submit = (person: MyApp.Models.Person) => {
  //Access person values
}
```

The problem is when inspecting the `person` value on calling `submit()` it is `undefined` and not populated.

I'd like to know if it's possible to have the multiple `<input>` form values from within the `form` element automatically used and bound to the object argument that is known by TypeScript in the `submit()` method?

The answer may be this is entirely *not* possible, but I'd like to know before I manually have to get each `ng-model` value and hydrate a `Person` instance from within my `submit()` function.

Comment: golden rule....always have a dot in ng-model (or [] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  And [some say it is even a recommended strategy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=1758s).

Rather than use the members of the `person` object directly on your form elements (`ng-model=FirstName`), use dot notation with a person object (`ng-model=person.FirstName`).  For example on your scope object:

```
$scope.person: MyApp.Models.Person;
```

and in your markup (note the difference on your `ng-model`):

```
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="person.FirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
```

Now when you call your `submit` function, you can send it the `person` model

```
ng-submit="submit(person)"
```

and your `submit` function `person` parameter will have access to all the members of the `person` object defined on your form.

Comment: more than just a recommended strategy....it's really a "must do" when dealing with child scopes since primitive bindings get broken

Comment: @charlietfl - agreed.  :)

Comment: Fantastic! Worked like a charm :D